# compare two files with different column and row numbers

Tags: perl, awk

I want to compare two big files with different column and row numbers and print those line which have a common word (like `KJ`):

file1:

```
XT1 123 aa NR
XT2 444 bb GF 
XT3 666 aa KJ
```

file2

```
fc KK pcn
wd CC KJ
```

output

```
XT3 666 aa wd CC KJ
```

I tried but I didn't get anything:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$4]=$3;next}{if (a[$3])print a[$3],$0}' file1 file2
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you asking to match up all pairs of lines that share any common word, regardless of where in the file they occur? If `file` was as shown, but `file2` had 100,000 lines of other data prior to the two lines you show, would you still want that match to appear?

Comment: What if a line from file1 matched more than one line from file2, or vice-versa. What if the matches were on different fields?

Comment: I want to print only those pairs of lines that share any common word in $4 (file1) and $3(file2).

Comment: names in $3 and $4 are uniqe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the limited info you provided,

```
my $file1 = '...';
my $file2 = '...';

my %file2;
{
   open(my $fh2, '<', $file2)
      or die("Can't open \"$file2\": $!\n');
   while (<$fh2>) {
      my @F = split;
      $file2{$F[2]} = join(' ', @F[0,1]);
   }
}

{
   open(my $fh1, '<', $file1)
      or die("Can't open \"$file1\": $!\n');
   while (<$fh1>) {
      my @F = split;
      print(join(' ', @F[0..2], $file2{$F[3]}, $F[3]), "\n")
         if $file2{$F[3]};
   }
}
```

I assumed the following:

- `file2` fits in memory as a hash of lines.
- A keyword doesn't appear twice in `file2`.
- You're only interested in matching the 4th column of `file1` with the 3rd column of `file2`.

It maintains the order of the lines as they appear in `file1`.

Answer (score 2):

You were close, try this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$4]=$1 FS $2 FS $3; next } $3 in a { print a[$3], $0 }' file1 file2
```

Results:

```
XT3 666 aa wd CC KJ
```

Quick explanation:

> In 'file1', add column 4 to an array with columns 1, 2 and 3 as it's values.
>
> In 'file2', check if column 3 is in the array and if it is, print out it's value and the current line.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a separate hash of words to lines numbers for each file,
and an array storing each line, for each file.

then I'd iterate of the list of words in file 1, and look for a match in file 2.
If I find a match, then I'd look up the line numbers for the word in both files.
Using the line number, I'd retrieve the "lines" form the arrays, and return the list of unique words.